# WP Как понять что пользователь верифицирован оставлять комментарии?

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

В `WordPress` есть переключатель, который гарантирует, что если пользователю одобрили один комментарий, то следующие может публиковать без предварительной модерации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где содержиться параметр в базе данных, что текущий пользователь "верифицированный" ? (по `$user_id`)

*Моя задача состоит в том, что б если пользователю разрешено оставлять комментарии, что б возле него отображался бейджик "Провереный пользователь"

Comment: Если ничего не путаю, то прямо в базе это не хранится, так-то в таблице `wp_comments` есть колонка `comment_approved`, но она имеет отношение к конкретному комментарию.

Comment: Не, это то, что комментарий разрешон и его можно публиковать... там comment_approved = '0' '1' 'spam' 'trash' Это именно про комментарий.  Меня же интересует, как WP понимает, что теперь у данного пользователя все комментарии будут установлены в comment_approved = '1' по умолчанию. Хотя у него таже роль что и других... Но у других пользователей изначально после публикации становиться comment_approved = '0' а этому comment_approved = '1'

Comment: То что Вас интересует как WP понимает, не очень релевантно для Вашего случая, потому что это работает не так как Вы себе представляете. Эта проверка происходит во время добавления комментария, в функции [wp_new_comment()](https://wp-kama.com/function/wp_new_comment) вызывается функция [wp_allow_comment()](https://wp-kama.com/function/wp_allow_comment) где и происходит ряд проверок, в том числе вызов функции [check_comment()](https://wp-kama.com/function/check_comment)

Comment: Спасибо. А по какому параметру тогда можна отслеживать ? Я наивно полагал, что где-то в `wp_usermeta` есть то что это контролирует, но не нашел.

Comment: Можете посмотреть код функции [check_comment()](https://wp-kama.com/function/check_comment) на 131 строке там идет получение пользователя через email `$comment_user = get_user_by( 'email', wp_unslash( $email ) );` и если такой пользователь есть, то `$wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT comment_approved FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE user_id = %d AND comment_approved = '1' LIMIT 1", $comment_user->ID ) );`

Comment: Ага, тоесть они делают запрос в базу на кокретного пользователя, и если у этого пользователя есть хоть один `comment_approved = '1' ` тогда можно считать, что он верифицирован... Понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот функция, код которой извлечен из check_comment().

В неё надо передать почту и имя пользователя (если он не зарегистрирован). Она вернёт true, если комментарии для пользователя были одобрены.

Код протестирован для существующего пользователя.

```php
/**
 * Check if user is approved for commenting.
 *  Extracted from check_comment() WP Core function.
 *
 * Check if the option to approve comments by previously-approved authors is enabled.
 *
 * If it is enabled, check whether the comment author has a previously-approved comment,
 * as well as whether there are any moderation keywords (if set) present in the author
 * email address. If both checks pass, return true. Otherwise, return false.
 *
 * @param string $email Email.
 * @param string $author Author name.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_user_approved( $email, $author = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( 1 !== (int) get_option( 'comment_previously_approved' ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $comment_user = get_user_by( 'email', wp_unslash( $email ) );

    // phpcs:disable WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery, WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.NoCaching
    if ( ! empty( $comment_user->ID ) ) {
        $ok_to_comment = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT comment_approved FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE user_id = %d AND comment_approved = '1' LIMIT 1",
                $comment_user->ID
            )
        );
    } else {
        // Variables $author and $email are expected to be slashed.
        $ok_to_comment = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT comment_approved FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_author = %s AND comment_author_email = %s and comment_approved = '1' LIMIT 1",
                $author,
                $email
            )
        );
    }
    // phpcs:enable WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery, WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.NoCaching

    $mod_keys = trim( get_option( 'moderation_keys' ) );

    return (
        ( 1 === (int) $ok_to_comment ) &&
        ( empty( $mod_keys ) || ! str_contains( $email, $mod_keys ) )
    );
}
```